# Blue Screen Error 0x000000b8

Tags: windows-10, bsod, troubleshooting, windows-error-reporting

I just bought a DELL Inspiron 5408 7 Days ago. I was watching a TV series (Full HD) on VLC Media Player. Suddenly in the middle of an episode, my laptop froze and blue-screen appeared.

Details:
**Bug check code
0x000000b8 

Bug check parameters

0xffffad85a2132140,
0xffffad85c3040080,
0x0000000000000000,
0x0000000000000000**

I scanned the pc and found this:
**Hardware Scan Result (Web) - BSOD - Warning - November 2, 2020 8:16:30 AM**

Please Help me with this

Edit: I am using windows 10 home(always up to date). Works fine since then.

Comment: And what happened after you shut down and rebooted??

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Go to DELL and make sure you have updated drivers.  Without a mini-dump there is no way to tell what your computer was doing to make it crash.  Here is [your error](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xb8--attempted-switch-from-dpc).  It is most certainly a bug in a driver as the error is in a DPC routine.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Procedure_Call) is a description of what that is.  Chances are, updated device drivers will make it go away.  If it doesn't fix the problem, you will need to create a mini dump so we can figure it out.

Comment: Please tell how I can provide you more info

Comment: The blue screen occurred once and didn't reoccur, so it is unclear if there is a reproducible problem.